# How to find in an $a array a specific string?

Tags: php, arrays, search

```
// Array with names
$a[] = "Anna";
$a[] = "Brittany";
$a[] = "Cinderella";
$a[] = "Diana";
$a[] = "Eva";
$a[] = "Fiona";

// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$hint = "";

if ($q !== "") {
     $q = strtolower($q);
     echo array_search($q, $a);
 }
```

I just want to be able to search for one name, and get a response with the name. But I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Using `strtolower` you won't find anyting. E.g `fiona` != `Fiona`.

Comment: [`in_array(ucfirst($q), $a)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)